# difference between res.header(x-auth, JWTtoken) and res.cookies(JWTtoken)?

Tags: javascript, http, authentication, cookies, jwt

I have seen across all blogs and articles is that there is two ways to handle `JWTtokens`, put them inside `localStorage` which subjected for `XSS` attack or put them inside `Cookies` and set `httpOnly` and `secure` flags to avoid `XSS`.

**Using localStorage**
For every request to the server you extract the `token` out of the `localStorage` and append it to `Authorization : Bearer <Token>` manually.

**Using Cookies**
It is handled server side since it won't be accessed by `JS` client side, what you do is `res.cookies(token)`, and it is going to be sent automatically for every subsequent call unlike `localStorage`

But lately i saw some developers simply put the `token` in the headers using `res.headers('x-auth', token)`.

1. Is it a third way to handle JWT?
2. Would the X-Auth header set for every subsequent request to the server like cookies automatically or you have to set it manually (like in case of localStorage) ?
3. Are tokens in X-Auth header cannot be accessed by JS and secure like cookies?
4. what is the difference between doing it your way res.header('X-auth') and res.cookie(token) ?
5. Finally what is the best way to do it if my API is consumed by by ReactJS web app and react-native mobile application?

Thanks

Comment: Did you figure this out? I am also curious how this is different from sending the JWT in the `"Authorization: Bearer <token>"` header